# What is name of this soundtrack?

Tags: metal, videogame-soundtrack

It plays while Boss of current stage is entering the arena. Game's name is "Swords and Sandals" (version 1 probably).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBh0EdT2bso

What is the music in this soundtrack called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Swords and Sandals II and if I'm not mistaken this music plays only during battle with John the Butcher. It's not easy to find all music from SS, but maybe you will find it here: https://soundcloud.com/oliverjoyce

Oliver Joyce is developer and composer from team 3RDSense, creators of Swords and Sandals.